# Foursquare venues exclusions

Tags: api, foursquare

In 4square venues [API reference](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) I've found parameter `categoryId` for inclusion some category venues. But I want to exclude some categories from my venues list (e.g. trains and airplane check-ins).

Is this feature available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't, you'll need to retrieve the venues in the top-level category that you *do* want and then filter out those belonging to the categories that you *don't* want.